# Is there a way to get UserId out of Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to get User Id out of Spring Security, currently I found this solution:

```java
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
   String username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
   User user = userRepository.findAllByUsername(username);

}
```

And then use that user.getId() method.. Is there no built in way I can get the ID easier? Or can I modify my UserDetailsService to include the ID?

I'm very new to this framework. I read that using another repository could help, but I don't want another one just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your main concern is not to repeat this code every time you need the ID of a logged in user? If this is the case, just move this code to some service, say UserService:

```java
    @Service
    public class UserService {
         public User getLoggedInUser(long id) {
             // your code from original post goes here
         }
    }
```

and then include this service in the class. that you intend to use this functionality and use it. Say your class is called is a kind of RestController called MyController:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController{
    private UserService userService;

    public MyController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        User authUser = userService.getLoggedInUser();
    }
}
```

or if you need ID only, change the method to return ID and use it instead:

```
long userId = userService.getLoggedInUserId();
```

The code inside the new UserService method would be the same as in your question above, but the code that uses it in MyController will be much more readable.

Should you need this ID only to check permissions, please [look into](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SMTH')")` or other similar annotations from Spring Security instead.

Comment: UserService would be a regular Java class with @Service annotation. There is nothing that makes it special or different from any other service you might create in Spring. I updated my answer to include a simple example.